# Nightwatch in Docker - selenium-server can't find chromedriver

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, selenium-server

I am trying to launch Nightwatch inside a Docker container.

I am getting an error from `selenium-server` which basically states that `chromedriver` could not be found. I can manually verify that the file that (I think) it's looking for does exist.

I have created a sample repository to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/hvolschenk/nightwatch-docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working, had to change my `Dockerfile` a bit.

```
FROM openjdk:latest

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y google-chrome-stable

WORKDIR /home/node/app

CMD ["npm", "test"]
EXPOSE 5555
```

So, as opposed to adding `openjdk` from a `node` image, I am adding `node` to an `openjdk` image.

Still not quite sure why the previous iteration didn't work, regardless, got to move forward.

**Edit**:

I also found a way to run this from a `node` docker image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon

RUN echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -t jessie-backports -y openjdk-8-jre

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y google-chrome-stable

ENV HOME /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
VOLUME ["/home/node/app"]

RUN chown -Rv node:node /home/node/app
USER node

CMD ["npm", "test"]
EXPOSE 5555
```